# Alert box not printing variable values

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript and I am playing around with functions right now and I am trying to alert the user what they entered, but when I type in the first name and last name and email and press subscribe, the alert box says :

```
Hello [object HTMLInputElement] [object HTMLInputElement]! Your email [object HTMLInputElement] was succesfully registered ...
```

This is my code:

```
<script>
    function printMessage(firstNameID,lastNameID,emailID){
        var firstName = document.getElementById(firstNameID);
        var lastName = document.getElementById(lastNameID);
        var email = document.getElementById(emailID);
        alert("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "! Your email " + email + " was succesfully registered ...");
    }
</script>
<form name="subscribeform">
    First Name: <br>
<input type="textbox" id="firstname" form="subscribeform"><br>
    Last Name: <br>
<input type="textbox" id="lastname" form="subscribeform"><br>
    Email: <br>
    <input type="textbox" id="email" form="subscribeform"><br><br>
    <button id="subscribe" form="subscribeform" onclick="printMessage('firstname','lastname','email');">Subscribe, you know you want to ...</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `value` of the elements, not the elements themselves.

```
alert("Hello " + firstName.value + " " + lastName.value + "! Your email " + email.value + " was succesfully registered ...");
```

or...

```
var firstName = document.getElementById(firstNameID).value;
var lastName = document.getElementById(lastNameID).value;
var email = document.getElementById(emailID).value;
```